# InventTransType table reference

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

In AX2009, how is it possible to find the table that is related to an InventTransType in the code?

For instance, InvnetTransType::Sales is related to the SalesTable, but how is it possible to get the table id or table name from SalesTable in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible, because there is no 1:1 relationship between the elements of the `InventTransType` enum and tables. At best there is a 1:n relationship (e.g. you could argue that `InventTransType::Sales` is related to table `SalesLine` just as well or even better as table `SalesTable`). Note also that the documentation on the enum says that it specifies "[the module that generated the transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa574913(v=ax.50).aspx)".

It really depends on the question you ask and the data you want to retrieve. That said, here are some points you could research, maybe one of them fits your question/requirements. If all else fails, you can always write your one mapping method that takes an enum element and gives you the id of the table you think is appropriate for this element(standard AX does this in several cases to map other entities to the enum elements, see for example table `InventDimSetup`, method `transType2FieldId`).

- cross references: check the cross references of the enum or of an enum element, that should give you an idea which table(s) are associated with which element
- relations of table `InventTrans`: for some of the enum elements, you can find table relations in table `InventTrans` (but unfortunately not for all of them); ponus point is that by using reflection, you can analyze the relations and get the referenced table (which is probably as close to your requirement as it can get in standard AX)